# How customize Cubism.js plugin to accept data from other sources like a two dimensional data array

Tags: d3.js, timeserieschart, cubism.js

I'm new to Javascript. There's a requirement to draw a time series graph using cubism.js with the data from a two-dimensional data array.
Is there anyone who have tried this already?
Can anyone help me to solve this tricky part?

Here is my code, in `evo-timetest.js` (also available on [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0gpostohfv42p9u/evo-timetest.js?dl=0)):

```
define( [ "jquery", "css!./style.css","./d3.v3.min", "./cubism.v1"],
    function (  $, d3,cubism) {     
        paint: function ( $element, layout ) {

                //Check data in console
                console.log($element);
                console.log(layout);

                // Data Array
                var qMatrix = layout.qHyperCube.qDataPages[0].qMatrix;

                //Dimension Lables
                var DimensionLabels = layout.qHyperCube.qDimensionInfo.map(function (d) {
                    return d.qFallbackTitle;
                });
                var test = DimensionLabels.map(function(i){return i;})
                console.log(test);

                //Store each data into objects
                var data = qMatrix.map(function(d){
                    return{
                        "Dim1":d[0].qText,
                        "Metric1":d[1].qNum
                    }
                });
                var map = data.map(function(i){return i.Metric1;})
                console.log(map);
                // Store chart object width, height, and Id
                var width = $element.width();

                var height = $element.height();

                var id = "container_" + layout.qInfo.qId;

                if(document.getElementById(id)){
                    $('#' + id).empty();
                }
                else{
                    $element.append($('<div/>').attr("id",id).width(width).height(height));
                }

                // Call visualization function
                viz(data,DimensionLabels,width,height,id);

                }
    };

} );

var viz = function(data,lables,width,height,id){


/*    
    // create context and horizon
                var context = cubism.context().size(960)
                var horizon = context.horizon().extent([0,2])

                // define metric accessor
                function random_ma(name) {
                return context.metric(function(start,stop,step,callback){
                var values = [];
                while (+start < +stop){
                    start = +start +step; 

                    values = data.map(function(i){return i;})

                    console.log(values);

                }
            callback(null, values);
                }, name);
                }

            // draw graph
            var metrics = ["foo","bar","baz"];
            horizon.metric(random_ma);

            d3.select("#graph").selectAll(".horizon")
            .data(metrics)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class", "horizon")
            .call(horizon);

            // set rule
            d3.select("#"+id).append("div")
            .attr("class", "rule")
            .call(context.rule());



            // set focus
            context.on("focus", function(i) {
            d3.selectAll(".value")
            .style( "right", i == null ? null : context.size() - i + "px");
            });
            // set axis 
            var axis = context.axis()
            d3.select("#graph").append("div").attr("class", "axis").append("g").call(axis);


            } 
*/           

//Defenition of Visualization function


//***************************************************************************************************************************

/* console.log(data);
console.log(lables); */
/* //var dF = new Date(2013,12,31)
var context = cubism.context();
//      .serverDelay(Date.now() - dF)
        // .step(864e5)
        // .size(1280)
        // .stop();

d3.select("#" + id).selectAll(".axis")
    .data(["top", "bottom"])
    .enter().append("div")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return d + " axis"; })
    .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(context.axis().ticks(12).orient(d)); });

d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "rule")
    .call(context.rule());

var Data = lables.map(function(i){return i;})
// var primary = Data[1];
// var secondary = primary.shift(-864e5*30); 
// Data[2] = secondary;

d3.select("body").selectAll(".horizon")
    .data(Data)
  .enter().insert("div", ".bottom")
    .attr("class", "horizon")
  .call(context.horizon()
    .format(d3.format("+,.2p")));

context.on("focus", function(i) {
  d3.selectAll(".value").style("right", i == null ? null : context.size() - i + "px");
});
 */


/****************************************************************************************************************/



/* console.clear();


    // create new cubism.js context to render
    var graphContext = cubism.context();
  //      .serverDelay(1000) // allow 1second delay
  //      .step(1000) // 1 second steps
   //     .size(650); // 50px wide

    // create a new metric
    // this allows you to retrieve values from some source
    // this is data-source agnostic, so this does not matter.
    var graphMetric = graphContext.metric(function(start, stop, step, callback) {
        var values = [];
        start = +start;
        stop = +stop;
        while (start < stop) {
            start += step;
            values.push(Math.random());
        }
        callback(null, values);
    });


    // here we create a new element and then append it to our
    // parent container. Then we call d3 to select the newly created
    // div and then we can create a chart
    var graphElement = document.createElement("div");
    $("#insertElement").append(graphElement);    
    d3.select(graphElement).call(function(div) {
       div.selectAll(".horizon")
            .data([graphMetric])
            .enter().append("div")
            .attr("class", "horizon")
            .call(graphContext.horizon()
                  .height(150)
             ); 
       div.append("div")
            .attr("class", "axis bottom")
            .call(graphContext.axis().orient("top"));
        div.append("div")
            .attr("class", "rule")
            .call(graphContext.rule());
                */



  /**********************************************************************************************************/
/*   d3.select("#" + id).selectAll(".axis")
    .data(["top", "bottom"])
    .enter().append("div");
  var chart = d3.timeseries()
              .addSerie(data,{x:'date',y:'n',diff:'n3'},{interpolate:'monotone',color:"#333"})
              .width(900);
chart('#chart');
   */


}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Hi Christopher,
I have used the following code to draw a graph but it failed.
     Please refer to the dropbox link:https://www.dropbox.com/s/0gpostohfv42p9u/evo-timetest.js?dl=0
Could you please help to solve this issue. I think that it necessary to customise Cubism.js library to accept data from a Data array. 
I'm new to this javascript world. The ultimate requirement for me is to draw an area chart with the layered band as in time series graph drawn using cubism.js

Thank you